# how to show an inequality from P.D.E

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ a regular bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$.  Let $T>0$, $u_0 \in L^2$, $b \in L^{\infty}(]0,T[\, \times\, \Omega)^N$, and $c \in L^{\infty}(]0,T[\, \times\, \Omega)$.
We consider the following equation on $]0,T[\, \times\, \Omega$.

$\partial_{t} u+b \cdot \nabla u+c u-\Delta u=0$

$u|_{\partial \Omega} =0$
and $u|_{t=0}=u_0$ .

> **Question**: Show that if $u \in C^1([0,T],C^2(\Omega)) $ is a   solution then
> $\frac{d}{d t}\|u(t)\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u(t, x)|^{2} d x \leq\left(2\|c\|_{\infty}+\|b\|^2_{\infty}\right)\|u(t)\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}$.

**My attempt**:  I can show that $$\frac 12 \frac{d}{d t}\|u(t)\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u(t, x)|^{2} d x \leq\|c\|_{\infty}\|u(t)\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+|\int_{\Omega} (b \cdot \nabla u)u |$$
How to continue with this term  $|\int_{\Omega} (b \cdot \nabla u)u |$?

Comment: thank you i corrected the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct so far. To estimate $|\int_\Omega (b\cdot \nabla u)u\, dx|$, first note $$|(b\cdot \nabla u)u| = |bu\cdot u|\le \frac12[|bu|^2 + |\nabla u|^2] \le \frac12[\|b\|_{\infty}^2|u|^2 + |\nabla u|^2]$$ Then $|\int_\Omega (b\cdot \nabla u)u\, dx| \le \frac12\|b\|_\infty^2 \|u(t)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \frac12\|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$, and hence $$\frac12 \frac{d}{dt}\|u(t)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \le \left(\|c\|_{\infty} + \frac12 \|b\|_\infty^2\right) \|u(t)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \frac12 \|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$$ Subtracting $\frac12\|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$ from both sides and multiplying by $2$ results in $$\frac{d}{dt}\|u(t)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}  \le (2\|c\|_\infty + \|b\|_\infty^2)\, \|u(t)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$$ as desired.